# Page becomes unresponsive when entering value in textbox in Angular4

Tags: angular

I want calculate tax of products entered in invoice . So for this I am using temalate driven forms .

below is little code

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of products; let i = index;">

                                <td> 
                                    <input type="number" name="qty{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.qty" />
                                </td>
                                <td> 
                                    <input type="number" name="rate{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.rate"/>
                                </td> 


                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="amount{{i}}"  value="{{ item.qty * item.rate }}" readonly /> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

and showing subtotal , total , nettotal  in another div. the code is below

```
                    <p class="all-t-list">
                        <span>Sub total</span>
                        <strong>Rs {{ getSubTotal() }}</strong>
                    </p>



                    <p class="all-t-list normal-txt">
                        <span>Shipping Charges</span>
                        <input type="number" #shipping_charges 
                        (keyup)="onKeyUpShippingValue(shipping_charges.value)" />
                    </p>

                    <p class="all-t-list normal-txt">
                        <span>Total</span>
                        <strong>Rs {{ totalAmount()}}</strong>
                    </p>

                    <p class="all-t-list">
                        <span>Deposit   </span>
                        <strong><input type="text" #deposit_charges  
                        (keyup)="onKeyUpDepositValue(deposit_charges.value)"/></strong>
                    </p>

                    <p class="all-t-list">
                        <span>Net Total   </span>
                        <strong>Rs {{netTotalAmount()}}</strong>
                    </p>

                    <p class="all-t-list">
                        <span>Balance due   </span>
                        <strong>Rs {{netTotalAmount()}}</strong>
                    </p>
```

Everything is working fine but when i am entering value qty and rate textboxes that time page become unresponsive. I dont know whats wrong with this code. Below is the code written in class file .

```
 actual_total : number = 0;
 shipping_charges : number = 0;
 deposit_charges : number = 0;


// it will count subtotal_cost
 getSubTotal(){
       console.log("getSubTotal method called");
       let subTotal : number = 0;
        this.products.forEach(function (item :any) {
            subTotal += item.qty * item.rate;
        });
        this.actual_total = subTotal;
        return subTotal;
 }


// it will caalculate discount on actual value      
getDiscount(){
  console.log("total is:"+this.actual_total);
  console.log("Discount is" );

}

// it will give you shipping value
onKeyUpShippingValue(event){
  debugger;
  this.shipping_charges = parseInt(event);
  if (isNaN(this.shipping_charges)){
    this.shipping_charges = 0;
  }
}

//calculate deposit charges
onKeyUpDepositValue(event){
  debugger;
  this.deposit_charges = parseInt(event);
  if (isNaN(this.deposit_charges)){
    this.deposit_charges = 0;
  }
}


//calculate netTotalAmount
netTotalAmount(){
      console.log("netTotalMethod called");
        var nettotal_amount : number = 0.0;
         nettotal_amount = this.actual_total - this.deposit_charges;
        // this.actual_total = nettotal_amount;
        return nettotal_amount; 
}

counter : number= 0;

//calculate balance due amount
balanceDueAmount(){
  console.log("balance due method called");
  var balance_due : number = 0.0;
  balance_due = this.actual_total - this.deposit_charges;
 // this.actual_tota11l = nettotal_amount;
  return balance_due;  
}


// calculate totalAmount
totalAmount(){
        let total : number = 0;
        this.products.forEach(function (item :any) {
            total += item.qty * item.rate;
        });
        total = total+this.shipping_charges;
        this.actual_total = total;
        return total;
   }
```

the function getSubtotal , totalAmount, balanceAmount calling infinite time so because of that page beocme unresponsive. So is there another way i can avoid the unresponsiveness???

Comment: Start by not modifying the state of your component from the methods bound to values in the template. Especially, don't modify this.actual_total from two of those methods, and don't rely on the state modification done in one of those methods to compute the value returned by another.

Comment: Just handle the logic in component and show variables in template.